# Understanding IEEE-754 64-bit fixed point representation in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, double, ieee-754

Consider the following Java code:

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double number = Double.MAX_VALUE;
      String formattedNumber = String.format("%f", number);
      System.out.println(formattedNumber);
    }
}
```

> 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

Consider the equivalent C# code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double value = double.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F"));
    }
}
```

> 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000

Given that the maximum value of `Double` is 1.7976931348623157E+308, to my knowledge, the Java output is correct; i.e. the floating-point value actually represents an integer where the first 17 digits are 17976931348623157, followed by 292 zeros.

Note: Converting `double` to `BigInteger` in C# yields the same result:

```cs
BigInteger value = (BigInteger)double.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

> 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368

**Questions**

- Why are the values wildly different, and which one should be considered correct?
- If C# is actually incorrect, how would I obtain the correct, or identical output that Java produced?

Comment: Ah, how to evaluate the equality of two double values! One of the eternal "why doesn't my program act _correctly_" questions. To my eyes, those two values are _equal_

Comment: @Flydog57 certainly their binary representation should be equal, otherwise one, or the other has implemented IEEE-754 incorrectly, but it does seem odd that they differ in representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Given that the maximum value of Double is 1.7976931348623157E+308…

This is incorrect. The format used for `Double` is the *binary64* or “double precision” format specified in the IEEE 754-2019 standard. In this format, a finite number is represented as ±*f*•2<sup>e</sup>, where *f*, the fraction portion of the representation, is the number represented by a binary numeral with one digit (0 or 1) before the radix point and 52 bits after it and *e*, the exponent, is an integer in [−1022, 1023]. So the maximum representable finite value is +1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>1023</sup>, which equals +(2<sup>1</sup>−2<sup>−52</sup>)•2<sup>1023</sup> = 2<sup>1024</sup>−2<sup>971</sup>, which is exactly 179,769,313,486,231,570,814,527,423,731,704,356,798,070,567,525,844,996,598,917,476,803,157,260,780,028,538,760,589,558,632,766,878,171,540,458,953,514,382,464,234,321,326,889,464,182,768,467,546,703,537,516,986,049,910,576,551,282,076,245,490,090,389,328,944,075,868,508,455,133,942,304,583,236,903,222,948,165,808,559,332,123,348,274,797,826,204,144,723,168,738,177,180,919,299,881,250,404,026,184,124,858,368, so the C# output is correct.

The Java output elides significant digits and conceals the true value. This is because the Java specification says that for the default formatting [“There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type `double`.”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double))

Comment: So, the C# value is actually more _correct_ than the Java value?

Comment: And, was that link intended to loop back to my own question?

Comment: @MatthewLayton: Re “So, the C# value is actually more correct than the Java value?”: Well, the C# value is correct, and the Java value is not correct, so you could call that more correct. The decimal numeral displayed by the C# code represents the same number than the `double` value represents, so it is correct. The decimal numeral displayed by the Java code represents a different number than the `Double` value represents, so I consider that to be incorrect. The Java output is obtained by rounding the `Double` to a certain number of digits, so Java deliberately produces a different number.

Comment: Yes, the link was supposed to be to the Java documentation; I must have copied the wrong URL into the paste buffer from the wrong browser tab. I approved the edit.