# How to obtain an "accurate", unscaled IEEE-754 floating point number in C#

Tags: c#, ieee-754, .net-generic-math

*I say **"accurate"** because IEEE-754 doesn't accurately represent decimal numbers, which seems to be the crux of the matter.*

All decimal numbers can be represented in scientific notation, as illustrated below. I have included a column for the unscaled value, which is the decimal value with all significant digits shifted to the left of the decimal point; for example:

| General | Scientific | Unscaled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.01 | [1.01e+0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.01e%2B0) | 101 |
| 0.025 | [2.5e-2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2.5e-2) | 25 |
| 123 | [1.23e+2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.23e%2B2) | 123 |
| 12345678 | [1.2345678e+7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.2345678e%2B7) | 12345678 |
| 123.456 | [1.23456e+2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.23456e%2B2) | 123456 |
| 12345.678901234567 | [1.2345678901234567e+4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1.2345678901234567e%2B4) | 12345678901234567 |
| *System.Double.MaxValue* | *1.7976931348623157e+308* | *17976931348623157 * (10 ^ 308)* |

The following code utilises .NET 7.0 generic math to obtain the exponent and mantissa from the IEEE-754 value, respectively. Note that they obtain the decimal (base 10) exponent and mantissa, **not** the binary (base 2) representation of them:

**GetExponent**

```cs
private static T GetExponent<T>(T value) where T : IBinaryFloatingPointIeee754<T>
{
    if (T.IsNaN(value) || T.IsInfinity(value) || T.IsZero(value)) return T.Zero;

    T absValue = T.Abs(value);
    T log10 = T.Log10(absValue);
    return T.Floor(log10);
}
```

**GetMantissa**

```cs
private static T GetMantissa<T>(T value) where T : IBinaryFloatingPointIeee754<T>
{
    T ten = T.CreateChecked(10);
    T exponent = GetExponent(value);
    T factor = T.Pow(ten, exponent);
    return value / factor;
}
```

Given the table above, these functions produce the following values:

| Scientific | Mantissa | Exponent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.01e+0 | 1.01 | 0 |
| 2.5e-2 | 2.5 | -2 |
| 1.23e+2 | 1.23 | 2 |
| 1.2345678e+7 | 1.2345678 | 7 |
| 1.23456e+2 | 1.23456 | 2 |
| 1.2345678901234567e+4 | 1.2345678901234567 | 4 |
| 1.7976931348623157e+308 | 1.7976931348623157 | 308 |

So far, so good! Now I want to multiply the mantissa by 10, until all significant digits are to the left of the decimal point. The following function obtains the unscaled mantissa:

```cs
private static BigInteger GetUnscaledMantissa<T>(T value) where T : IBinaryFloatingPointIeee754<T>
{
    T ten = T.CreateChecked(10);
    T mantissa = GetMantissa(value);
    T factor = T.One;

    // While the remainder isn't zero...
    while (mantissa * factor % T.One != T.Zero)
    {
        // ..multiply factor by 10.
        factor *= ten;
    }
    
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.CreateChecked(mantissa * factor);

    // trim any trailing zeros, which sometimes occurs.
    while (result % 10 == 0) result /= 10;

    return result;
}
```

Let's take a look at the results:

| Mantissa | Unscaled |
| --- | --- |
| 1.01 | 101 |
| 2.5 | 25 |
| 1.23 | 123 |
| 1.2345678 | 12345678 |
| 1.23456 | 123456 |
| **1.2345678901234567** | **12345678901234566** |
| **1.7976931348623157** | **17976931348623158** |

Generally speaking, the `GetUnscaledMantissa` function returns the correct value, however, notice the outliers highlighted in bold; they are not quite correct. It seems that in some cases the value is rounded up or down.

**Question**

Whilst I understand that this is just the nature of IEEE-754 binary floating point numbers, is there a way, or how could I modify the `GetUnscaledMantissa` function, so that it accurately returns the unscaled mantissa in all, or at least more/most cases?

(Note, I know that this is possible, it's just not trivial)

**Update**

Given the extended conversation on this topic, it seems that there is some confusion as to what I am trying to achieve, so hopefully the following goes some way to setting the record straight.

Forget IEEE-754 for the time being! Let's just focus on some pure maths.

The following numbers are expressed in scientific notation, and their equivalent full form:

**Table A**

| Scientific | Full |
| --- | --- |
| 1.00001e+50 | 100001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| -3.345233391e+45 | -3345233391000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
| 1.7976931348623157E+308 | 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |

These values in scientific notation can be verified in WolframAlpha; the maths checks out!

Now, the confusion seems to be around what happens when you represent the same numbers with IEEE-754.

The following numbers are expressed in scientific notation, and their equivalent full form, except this time, the full number is based on the IEEE-754 calculation:

**Table B**

| Scientific | Full |
| --- | --- |
| 1.00001e+50 | 100000999999999993488106414884841393099338118332416 |
| -3.345233391e+45 | -3345233391000000093465768949128568879123005440 |
| 1.7976931348623157E+308 | 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368 |

What I want `GetUnscaledMantissa` to return is the mathematically correct unscaled number (in Table A), **not** the IEEE-754 "correct" unscaled number (in Table B).

Comment: Can't you just parse `number.ToString("E")`

Comment: @KlausGütter, I could, but I'd like to avoid string parsing, if at all possible.

Comment: A double has 15 ~ 16 significant digits, `12345.678901234567` is already inaccurate.

Comment: @shingo Doesn't seem to be an issue: `Console.WriteLine(12345.678901234567);` prints the number exactly as specified, and my `GetMantissa` function also obtains it as `1.2345678901234567`.

Comment: The decimal number you see is just converted (sum up) from the binary number, `1.2345678901234567` and `12.345678901234567` are totally different in binary represention. You can see the last `7` because you are luck, you can try `Console.WriteLine(12345678901234567.0);`, the last digit becomes `8`.

Comment: @shingo The last digit becomes 8 when it's printed, but `GetMantissa(12345678901234567.0)` returns `1.2345678901234567` which is correct. Also `GetExponent(12345678901234567.0)` returns `16`, which aligns with your earlier comment.

Comment: in fact your mantisa is already not accurate since it should be  `1.79769313486231570814527423732e+308` (prolly this is still not accurate) for max double you lost precision doing math operation to get it

Comment: As decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in IEEE in general, you may have to be a bit more specific in your requirements. E.g. given a number x represented in IEEE-754, find a pair of integers (m, e) such that m*10^e is (1) represented by the same IEEE as x and (2) among all such pairs, m has the least number of digits.

Comment: @Selvin The mantissa is accurate in that the question states that it obtains the mantissa and exponent in base 10, **not** in base 2. I specifically don't want the binary representations because from a mathematical perspective, they do not produce the correct value; for example; `double.MaxValue`, which is 1.7976931348623157E+308 produces a 309 digit long, seemingly random sequence, but 1.7976931348623157E+308 in maths is 17976931348623157 with 292 trailing zeros.

Comment: @Selvin See my related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143839/understanding-ieee-754-64-bit-fixed-point-representation-in-c-sharp-and-java

Comment: `GetMantissa(12345678901234566.0), GetMantissa(12345678901234567.0), GetMantissa(12345678901234568.0)` return the same result.

Comment: `T.Pow(ten, exponent)` and `value / factor` already makes it not accurate

Comment: @Selvin in what way? i.e. the table of results from `GetExponent` and `GetMantissa` are producing the values I want.

Comment: `value` is `T` and `factor` is `T` where T is IEEE 754 number and dividing IEEE 754 numbers already adding inaccuracy

Comment: What I want to express is that the number of digits outside the range is not credible. If you print `1.2345678901234566` in C#, you will see `1.2345678901234567`, what's the unscaled number of `1.2345678901234566`? This may be a false proposition because you cannot even represent `1.2345678901234566` in the code.

Comment: @shingo hence the reason I stated "or at least more/most cases". Java's `BigDecimal` also suffers some edge cases in this respect: https://pl.kotl.in/Ahk0HeQIu FYI I deleted my last comment with the code example, because the example only accounted for one of the provided numbers, instead of all three.

Comment: So the case is the unscaled number can keep up to 15 digits, `GetMantissa (1.2345678901234567)=123456789012345`. Is this acceptable? The example you shown is wrong, it's not some edge cases of `BigDecimal`, but it's still the problem of double (as same as the one in this question), because the numbers you passed to `BigDecimal.valueOf` is already inaccurate. https://pl.kotl.in/RWdgJo1hF if I change the parameters to string, the `BigDecimal` works.